# asp.net mvc web api ignore property on response ONLY

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am aware of `[JsonIgnore]` attribute. Unfortunatelly it ignores property on both, the Request and the Response.

I need a way to **ONLY** ignore it during **RESPONSE**. Having to work with two different classes for request and response (even by using inheritance) is not an acceptable solution as it introduces a whole a lot of object copying hassle.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's absolutely fine and often necessary to use two separate classes for request and response of the same Action. Why do you think it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

JsonIgnore instructs the JsonSerializer not to serialize the public field or public read/write property value for both request and response.

It sounds like you have a design issue. Create your request/response data contracts separately and more properly.